# How can I use a Record's value as an object key whose interface is the same type

Tags: typescript

I have a type defined that is an OR of strings(this cannot be an enum due to unrelated circumstances)

```
export type AnimalTypes =
    | 'dog'
    | 'cat'
    | 'donkey'
    | 'elephant';
```

I use this type as the value in an exported `Record`

```
export const PartyTypes: Record<string, AnimalTypes> = {
    DOG_PARTY: 'dog',
    CAT_PARTY: 'cat',
    DEMOCRAT_PARTY: 'donkey',
    REPUBLICAN_PARTY: 'elephant',
};
```

In a separate file I import the two above and make an interface with the `AnimalType` as the key

```
interface ElectionState {
    votesByParty: Record<AnimalTypes, PartyVotesCollection>;
}
```

When I try to make an object literal implementing this interface using the `PartyTypes` Record I get an error on the object key

```
export const initialState: ElectionState = {
    votesByParty: {
        PartyTypes.DOG_PARTY: {
            electionsWon: 0,
            voteCount: 0,
        },
    },
};
```

> Type '{ PartyTypes: Record<string, AnimalTypes>; "": any; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<AnimalTypes, PartyVotesCollection>'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'PartyTypes' does not exist in type 'Record<AnimalTypes, PartyVotesCollection>'.ts(2322)

What can I do to use the value of a Record as the key in another object that inherits from an interface?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCA7AlgWwIYA2AKssAM5wC8AUHHXAD5wDkAJhAObO31PMDGeGN3qMW7DAGtgiEbxbACwMAAs8GYQG5q1UJFhx%20EDGXgAFPLEQkUZAFxwASsCNRWAHlNQsGDgBp0bHxiUjIAPio4AG8eOgARAHkAcQB9MzRHIgBNBzZOZj9YuABhNCI0jOzcwWFC0TiAUQBZBOLHMorMnPFjaVk6%20kcGswBVACEAGQBJUoA5TqqFJVV1WuoAX21qHxhgKAAzPH5UBqV%20GCxjAGUYIVQY0QA3CF2yMcQLKwdnVw9MXEINnIAQwAFccAAjPZhbTrHR6aDwIwmeA%20LAXQg3O4OU4uC7XW67SIPejPV7vT5IBwk0R0SnWUIAOkSqXSXQcAAYBnR1oVNkA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to note:

```
export const initialState: ElectionState = {
    votesByParty: {
        PartyTypes.DOG_PARTY: 0,
    },
};
```

should be

```
export const initialState: ElectionState = {
    votesByParty: {
        [PartyTypes.DOG_PARTY]: 0,
    },
};
```

Also, the `votesByParty` type require *all* the parties ( unless you want to make a partial type out of it )

```
export const initialState: ElectionState = {
    votesByParty: {
        [PartyTypes.DOG_PARTY]: 0,
        [PartyTypes.CAT_PARTY]: 0,
        [PartyTypes.DEMOCRAT_PARTY]: 0,
        [PartyTypes.REPUBLICAN_PARTY]: 0,
    },
};
```

This is still erroring out, because `PartyTypes.DOG_PARTY` can be any kind of `AnimalTypes`, so we cannot guarantee that `votesByParty` will have all of them. After all, this:

```
export const PartyTypes: Record<string, AnimalTypes> = {
    DOG_PARTY: 'cat',
    CAT_PARTY: 'cat',
    DEMOCRAT_PARTY: 'cat',
    REPUBLICAN_PARTY: 'cat',
};
```

is still valid.

Because we need to be sure that `votesByParty` have all the parties in it, we need to change:

```
export const PartyTypes = {
    DOG_PARTY: 'dog',
    CAT_PARTY: 'cat',
    DEMOCRAT_PARTY: 'donkey',
    REPUBLICAN_PARTY: 'elephant',
} as const;
```

unless you want to remove the requirement of having all the parties in the object, in that case:

```
interface ElectionState {
    votesByParty: Partial<Record<AnimalTypes, number>>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, anyone else who stumbles on this: the Tl;Dr version is to surround your object key with `[]`